# jQuery Function Not Working on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I've got a jQuery function that usually works on a Volusion page and for some reason now it's not working. The location.pathname.indexOf targets all pages that have that URL (the site uses GET variables to do searches on the SearchResults.asp page). I've changed the quotations from singles to doubles and I can't seem to figure out anything else to do test it. Does anyone see any syntax errors in this code? There shouldn't be any conflicts since it's only running jQuery (and nothing else like MooTools). I tried to also do an alert of 'Test' after document.ready but nothing happened on the screen. Thanks!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if (location.pathname.indexOf('/SearchResults.asp') != -1 ) {
        $('div#content_area').css({'display','none !important'});         
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what if you try `$(document).on('ready',function(){...});`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?  Have you set a breakpoint before the inside the `ready` function and/or inside the `if` block?  If so, have the breakpoints been hit?

Comment: @Sharlike That will only work if the document isn't already ready and is recommended against in the api documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

This:

```
$('div#content_area').css({'display', 'none !important'});
```

Should be this:

```
$('div#content_area').css({'display': 'none !important'});
//                                  ^
//                                  |
//                                  | look here
```

---

When using [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) you can use 2 variations.

You can either use it to update a single property which uses the `,` to separate the name of the CSS property and the value, similar to this:

```
$('div#content_area').css('display', 'none !important');
```

Or you can use the new variation, added in jQuery 1.9 which allows you specify multiple styles at once allowing you to specify property-value pairs, similar to this:

```
$('div#content_area').css({
    'display': 'none !important',
    'border' : 'solid 1px red'
});
```

---

**css() and !important**

---

There seems to be an issue when trying to apply a style using `.css()` and `!important`. 
there is a bug which was raised a long time ago: The [**Ticket #2066**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066) which was closed and an alternative was shown in that ticked.

It mentions that as an alternative you can set the `cssText` similar to this when using the multi-style variation:

```
$('div#content_area').css({
    'cssText': 'display: none !important'
});
```

or this when using the single style variation:

```
$('div#content_area').css('cssText', 'display: none !important');
```

Though, as the ticked mentions, a word of caution:

> You have to be careful setting `cssText` since it sets/clears everything
>   in the css for that element.

Another alternative, which most likely is the safest given the side-effects of `cssText`, is to create a separate CSS class and apply that, similar to this:

```
.alwaysHide{
    display: none !important;
}
```

```
$('div#content_area').addClass('alwaysHide');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dude, you've got some hawk eyes there!

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot No it wouldn't, because it's an object.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment... posting as an answer because there is some confusion

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot: To prevent any confusion I have also added now an explanation of the available variations, including the one added in jQuery 1.9. Thanks for raising that as a possible issue.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I know that code looks right, I'm wondering if there must be some conflict then. I'll look at the console and see if anything is coming up.

Comment: There were no console errors on this code, it just wasn't being executed. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: @MxmastaMills: It is the `!important` part which seems to throw it off. Have a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/93EWL/) using your CSS. Without the `!important` it works but when you add it , it doesn't.

Comment: @MxmastaMills: I had another look around and you can use `cssText` to specify the style including `!important` I have edited my answer to include that information as well as the working syntax. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, that's a great answer but more importantly a great lesson in this jQuery's .css() function. I appreciate you digging around and uncovering these little quirks. This will definitely help me immensely moving forward!

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use 2 syntax styles.

Either, you need to do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        if (location.pathname.indexOf('/SearchResults.asp') != -1 ) {
            $('div#content_area').css('display','none !important');         
        }
    });
    </script>
```

or you need to use this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        if (location.pathname.indexOf('/SearchResults.asp') != -1 ) {
            $('div#content_area').css({'display' : 'none !important'});         
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Generally, I wouldn't use the object {} in this case because you're only setting 1 css style parameter.

Comment: Interesting suggestion... I ALWAYS use the object, particularly so that I don't run into the issue the OP is facing (different approaches for single vs multi assignments)

Comment: @Steve Let alone dealing with versioning changes when you add those brackets in the future if you will need to change multiple properties.

Comment: @Steve is can be quite useful if you are used to or like to use chaining methodology (D3.js is an example library that really pushes chaining).

It won't be as pretty here in the comments section, but it is quite legible in text editors:

$(".audioContainer").css("position","absolute").css("left", "200px").css("background-color", "#ff0").css("z-index", "1000");

//edited in: I can't do hard returns to break the chain structure in the comments section

Comment: I am familiar with chaining and I am not knocking your approach.  If that's what you prefer, there is nothing wrong with it.  I personally feel `$(".audioContainer").css({"position":"absolute","left":"200px","background-color":"#ff0","z-index":"1000"});` is much more readable (if indented correctly over several lines). Plus it doesn't call the `css` method several times.

Comment: Personally, I use "","" for when I want to only specify 1 css style attribute and I {:} for when I do multiple.

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot: +1 for showing both variations. I thought about what you said regarding the confusion and decided to add a more detailed explanation as well just in-case. Thanks again for have brought it up.